# Как с помощью кода перейти на страницу в Гугл плей маркет , и как сделать правильную последовательность отображения компонентов AlertDialog?

Tags: java

Как с помощью кода перейти на мою страницу  в Гугл плей маркет ?
1.Хочу добавить сюда ( .setPositiveButton)
2.Хочу чтобы отображалось в такой последовательности

1.Больше не напоминать и выйти
2.Потом и выйти
3.Хочу

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Хотите оставить отзыв ?")



                .setNegativeButton("Больше не напоминать и выйти.",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface  arg0, int arg1) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })


                .setNeutralButton("Потом и выйти.",  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface  arg0, int arg1) {
                        MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })

                .setPositiveButton("Хочу!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface  arg0, int arg1) {
                        //
                    }
                })


                .create().show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `Intent`:

```
final String appPackageName = getPackageName(); // getPackageName() from Context or Activity object
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName)));
}
```

Пример взял [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753000/how-to-open-the-google-play-store-directly-from-my-android-application).

Comment: Не работает на api 16  на 28 все работает.Что можно сделать?

Comment: Можно опираясь на замысел реализованный в примере, доработать реализацию с учётом особенностей API 16. Но, это уже сами.